# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes

Tags: node.js, nodes, monodevelop

I am learning node.js on my own and I do not understand why I get that error `"[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting.."`. I have the same code as the one on the tutorial. What can be wrong?

Thank you for your help!

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');


//create connection 
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '123456',
});

//connect

db.connect((err)=>{
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("mysql is CONNECTED");
});


const app = express();

app.get('/createdb',(req,res) =>{
    let sql = 'CREATE DATABASE nodemysql';
    db.query(sql,(err, result)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send('database created');
    })
})

app.get('/createdb',()=>{
    console.log("server started on port 3000");
})

app.listen('3000',()=>{
    console.log("server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Have you created the database that you are trying to connect to?

Comment: Hi Brady, just did it and still the same error...

Comment: Try and add the console.error as suggested by Peter in the answers and post the error you are receiving in your question!

Comment: @FreshmanUCSD do you need any more help with this question? Please let me know or mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: I have a question if you have some time, when I am doing npm install --save mysql express, I got this error: "the git repository has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled". Seems that I am not doing this is the good repository? where should I install mysql and express?

Comment: @FreshmanUCSD please look at this post: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/336129).

Try this: create a `.gitignore` file with `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `mysql` is installed:

```sh
npm install mysql --save
```

Try `console.error(err)` followed by `return`:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "example.org",
  user: "bob",
  password: "secret"
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("error connecting: " + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log("connected as id " + connection.threadId);
});
```